# What is the default data-type for variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, let

I am working on a little challenge to learn Javascrcipt in an applied sense, and not just learning the 'theory' of it.

Part of the code I'm writing is as follows:

```
let count;
splitStory.forEach(function(element) {
  if (overusedWords.includes(element)) {
     count = count + 1;
  }
})
console.log(count);
```

When I run the function, it logs `NaN` to the console. However, when I change `let count;` to `let count = 0`, it logs the proper number that should be logged to the console. As I've learned, using the `let` declaration for a variable is valid, but in this case, there seems to be a problem. If I were to replace `count = count + 1;` to `count = 'sample_string'`, it works and logs `'sample_string'` to the console. This leads to my question, is the default data type of a variable a string unless otherwise specified in the declaration?

Comment: javascript variables are untyped - but `let count;` is equivalent to `let count = uindefined`

Comment: The default _value_ is `undefined`. `undefined + 1` is `NaN`. `NaN + 1` is also `NaN`.

Comment: Searched expecting there to be zillions of duplicates.  Found one dupe and it doesn't fully address the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jaromanda said earlier in comments, javascript is an **untyped language** or sometimes may refer as **weakly type** (Which is not an appropriate phrase because JS itself don't have compiler at all) which means that a **JavaScript variable can hold a value of any data type**.

---

### What is the problem?

Typically **when you define something like this: `let count;`, `count` itself will remain uninitialized until you assign something to it directly.** So, in this case, the unassigned **value element type is `undefined` which has a value `undefined`**, then whenever you try to `console.log` such a thing it will be undefined, let's look at this example.

```js
let count;

console.log('count type is:', typeof count)
console.log('count value is:', count)
```

You can see both type and value of `count` are `undefined`.

**NOTE:** You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) for more information.

Let's look at your particular example

```js
let count;

console.log('count type after declaration is:', typeof count);
console.log('count value after declaration is:', count);

let splitStory = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let overusedWords = ['d', 'b', 'e'];

splitStory.forEach(function(element) {
  if (overusedWords.includes(element)) {
     count = count + 1;
  }
})

console.log('count type at the end is:', typeof count);
console.log('count value at the end is:', count);
```

### So what's going on here?

**As @Patrick earlier said `undefined + 1` is `NaN`**, what does it mean even? **`NaN` (indicates Not-A-Number) itself is another datatype** (which rarely used). But why the result of `undefined + 1` is `NaN`? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), **whenever the expected result should be a number but due to several conditions it gets fail** like `Math.sqrt(-1)` **the result will be `NaN` also.** So, in this case, the **expected output of `count + 1` is a number** since we are doing arithmetic operation and want to increment `count` value by `1`, so **since the `count` value itself is `undefined` the operation of incrementing is impossible** (Because the `undefined` is non-configurable property), so the result will be `NaN`.

---

Let's jump into your second clause.

```js
let count = 'sample_string';

console.log('count type after declaration is:', typeof count);
console.log('count value after declaration is:', count);

let splitStory = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let overusedWords = ['d', 'b', 'e'];

splitStory.forEach(function(element) {
  if (overusedWords.includes(element)) {
    count = count + 1;
  }
})

console.log('count type at the end is:', typeof count);
console.log('count value at the end is:', count);
```

### What's happening here?

The output is `sample_string1` why though? The short answer is they will concatenate.

**In JavaScript, the `+` operator is used for both numeric addition and string concatenation. When you "add" a number to a string the interpreter converts your number to a string and concatenates both together.** So, since the type of `count` is `string`, in this `count + 1` operation JS itself considers `1` as a string also.

---

### What we should do to prevent such things?

It's simple, we should always keep in mind whenever we define a variable we should also indicate its type by assign a value to it.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript supports **variable typing**. It modifies the data type of the variable according to its value at run time.

For example if you initialized a variable with some 'string' value like -

```
let count = 'someString';   //data type would be string
```

And later on if you again assign some number value like -

```
count = 23        // data type of count becomes number
```

However if you don't assign any value and just declare the variable, it's data type is **"undefined".**

So in your case when you write:  `let count;`
This is equal to:

```
let count = undefined;
```

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Answer (score -2):

The default value of a variable declared with var or let is *undefined*, UNLESS you initialize it to a value, in which case, it gets the type of the value. If you don't initialize it, then it will not get a type until it was set to a certain value.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var